# Assert.AreEqual(..) failing

Tags: nunit

I have

```
var xmlConfiguration = InitTestConfiguration();
var xmlConfiguration2 = InitTestConfiguration();
Assert.AreEqual(xmlConfiguration, xmlConfiguration2);
```

And I get this error:

```
Expected: <XmlConfiguration`1[Tests.TestConfiguration]>
But was:  <XmlConfiguration`1[Tests.TestConfiguration]>
```

Where `XmlConfiguration` is a class containing a string and an integer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals checks for same reference (while you are creating two different objects with same values - different reference) and by your example i guess you are trying to check for state equality...

you can create a class that wraps XmlConfiguration and implement (by override) the Equal method and then it will work

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373358/nunit-doesnt-work-well-with-assert-areequal