# Assert.AreEqual fails on a class derived from List<> that overrides Equals()

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I've been having troubles with NUnit. I have a class that inherits from List and overrides Equals() (so two instances can be considered as equal when they contain the same elements in a different order). When using Assert.AreEqual, it fails, but using Assert.True and calling Equals manually works :

```
[Test]
public void Equals()
{
    var dieSet1 = new DieSet {new Die(1), new Die(2)};
    var dieSet2 = new DieSet {new Die(2), new Die(1)};

    Assert.True(dieSet1.Equals(dieSet2)); //ok
    Assert.AreEqual(dieSet1, dieSet2);    //fails with an exception
}
```

Here is the exception detail :

> NUnit.Framework.AssertionException was unhandled by user code
>    HResult=-2146233088
>    Message=  Expected and actual are both  with 2 elements
>    Values differ at index [0]
>    Expected: 
>    But was:
>
> Source=nunit.framework
>    StackTrace:
>         at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
>         at NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(Object expected, Object actual)
>         at DiceLibTest.DieSetTest.Equals() in c:\dev_code\DiceLib\DiceLibTest\DieSetTest.cs:line 47
>    InnerException:

I set a breakpoint in Equals(), and made sure it wasn't called when Assert.AreEqual was called.

My class is like this :

```
public class DieSet : List<Die>, IRollable
{
}
```

I've read some related questions, for instance :
[NUnit doesn't work well with Assert.AreEqual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373358/nunit-doesnt-work-well-with-assert-areequal)

But I double checked and my Equals() method has the correct signature.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
}
```

My guess is that NUnit internally has some special behaviors on List<> and/or arrays and/or collections in general, and that my class falls in one of these categories. My other guess is that I'm doing something wrong and I'm failing to see the obvious..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup - it's [documented](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalityAsserts&r=2.6.2):

> Beginning with version 2.4, multi-dimensioned arrays, nested arrays (arrays of arrays) and collections may be compared. Two arrays or collections will be treated as equal by Assert.AreEqual if they have the same dimensions and if each of the corresponding elements is equal.

So you probably want the `Assert.True` version instead, basically.

For *most* users, this behaviour is probably desirable - it just happens to conflict with your particular use.

Personally I wouldn't make a set-semantics type derive from `List<T>` to start with though - if you implemented `ISet<T>` instead (and used composition) then it may well just work.

Comment: ouch, It was in the manual, I must have missed that...

Thanks for the advice about implementing ISet and using composition instead.

Answer (score 3):

`CollectionAssert.AreEqual` or `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` are slightly more transparent ways of testing whether two collections contain the same elements either in the same order or in any order, respectively. I tend to try and use them if I know I'm comparing collections.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't know these methods !
I chose Jon Skeet's answer's as best answer, since I think it answers my question best, but your advice is actually very helpful, now I get a free trivial implementation of my Equals() method. I'm still hesitating whether i should really override equality, and now I'm really thinking maybe I should just use CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent when needed